# How to remove list from <?php the_category() ?>

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I am wondering how do I get just the permalink and name of the category of a post when using:

```
<?php the_category() ?>
```

The above outputs a list and I just want to be able to wrap the permalink and category in my own markup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) and [`get_category_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link):

```
<?php
// everything available
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo '<span><b>';
    echo $category->cat_ID . ' ';
    echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
    echo $category->category_nicename . ' '; 
    echo $category->category_description . ' '; 
    echo $category->category_parent . ' '; 
    echo $category->category_count . ' '; 
    echo '</b></span>';
} 
?>

<?php
// heres just the name and permalink:
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo $category->category_nicename . ' '; 
    echo get_category_link($category->cat_ID);;
} 
?>
```